# Double click broke in latest pantheon-files

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files

I'm not a single click fan, so double click being broke is really killing me.

Since the latest update of pantheon-files Double Click seems to be completely broke.  If I go back to Single Click everything works fine.  I've also noticed a broken screen icon in my dash now, probably related to something else that got installed with the latest updates, but maybe its related?

Comment: When you say "broke", could you instead describes what actually happens, and what you used to experience?

Comment: It used to be that you could set the single click setting to false (using `gsettings set org.pantheon.files.preferences single-click false`) and when you were in patheon-files instead of click opening a file automatically it selected it.  Double clicking (somewhat quickly) would open the file instead of clicking it and for folders double click would navigate down into the folder.  Now with that flag set to false clicking or double clicking selects, but never opens a item or navigates down into a child folder. For those of us with twitchy fingers single click opening things really screws us up.

Comment: It's possible this is a bug, but it's also possible the key just moved.

Comment: I am told a fix was committed yesterday, updating should fix this issue as far as anyone knows.

Comment: Seems like this was the related bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1546330

Comment: Ahh, yep that looks like my bug to follow :D  Guess it helps if your google foo is better than a 2 year olds :(.  Unfortunately mine fails me quite frequently, thanks for the link.  If you add it as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Are you using the daily PPA, such as in an unofficial Loki build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am told a fix was committed yesterday to trunk, or the daily PPA, updating should fix this issue as far as anyone knows. Seems like this was the related bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1546330